# EdgeNGramFilterFactory not working (not indexing?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am having trouble getting ngrams to work.  Here's my schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My database has a bunch of entries with

> "Elizabeth"

and

> "Elizabeths"

When I try to query on "Elizabeth" I get only "Elizabeth" and not "Elizabeths".
The odd thing is, when I check out the solr admin, the Analysis page shows that the EdgenGramFilterFactory is indeed available, and results in "Elizabeths" being expanded into

> e el  eli eliz    eliza   elizab  elizabe elizabet    elizabeth

It seems like the indexer isn't picking up on this.  I have the same problem when I move the synonyms filter from the query block to the index block.  That is to say, when I have the synonyms filter in the query block, it works, but when I put it in the index block, it has no effect.

I have restarted Sunspot and reindexed multiple times.  No dice.  Any ideas?  How can I directly check the indexed words list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem and it looks like a noob error.

In my model, is was using the following construct as per one of the tutorials:

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
 .
 .
 .
end

Sunspot.setup(Institution) do
  text :name
end
```

This did not seem to throw any errors when I started, stopped, or reindexed.  It struck me as strange that I was able to reindex immediately after stopping Solr.

I switched to

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
endH
```

When I did this, I found that I could not reindex after stopping Solr.  However, when I started Solr and reindexed, the index appeared to be truly
refreshed and my queries finally behaved as expected.