# Solr Sunspot minimum_match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm new to using Solr Sunspot for Rails. I'm trying to use the

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

So naturally not all of the tokens are going to match. I can't figure out how to use the minimum_match feature in my search http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/index.html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried and I just get 0 results:

```
Articles.search do
  fulltext params[:q] do
   :minimum_match => 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there. The hash syntax is when you're passing minimum match as a parameter to `fulltext`.

```
Article.search do
  fulltext params[:q], :minimum_match => 1
end
```

Within a block, you want a method invocation.

```
Article.search do
  fulltext params[:q] do
    minimum_match 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool. This works before I put in the EdgeNGramFilterFactory filter. Then once I do that I go back to getting 0 results. How do I use the EdgeNGramFilterFactory.

Comment: Ah, looks like you had two questions in one and I missed one of them. With the minimum_match invocation dealt with, you may want edit this question or post a new one with more details about your EdgeNGram setup. You might could include the changes you made to your schema.xml, sample input field values, and sample failing queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598114/edgengramfilterfactory-not-working-not-indexing