# Converting from Thinking Sphinx to Solr Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, sunspot, sunspot-rails

We are converting from Thinking Sphinx to Sunspot due to a few reasons. I have to rewrite the searching logic, however I am not sure how to convert the following:

I want to convert the search :any to Sunspot. This means not all of the keywords need to be present for the object to be a match. (Any of the keyword will do, and will be ordered by relevance). However I can't find it in the Sunspot documentation.

```
# Thinking Sphinx

search_result = Business.search([attributes[:name],attributes[:address]], match_mode: :any)
```

I also am looking for a way to easily add stopwords through Sunspot to Solr. Thinking Sphinx provides a way to specify it in yml. However there is no equivalent in Sunspot::Rails yml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Minimum match in Sunspot

> not all of the keywords need to be present for the object to be a match

In Solr this is the "minimum should match" concept. You can see some previous answers, a blog article of mine, and the Solr wiki docs on that subject:

- [Solr Sunspot minimum_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341694/solr-sunspot-minimum-match)
- [Websolr blog - Solr minimum_match](http://blog.websolr.com/post/1299174416/how-do-i-query-with-boolean-logic-using-sunspot)
- [Solr Wiki - DisMax mm parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29)

A similar query to what you've written above might look like this...

```
@search = Business.search do
  fulltext query_string, :minimum_match => 0
end
@businesses = @search.results
```

### Stopwords

For stopwords, I might start by recommending you *not* use them. Solr's DisMax algorithm should do a sufficient job ignoring common terms for the purpose of sorting results. The only time I have ever really needed stopwords was when generating word clouds by faceting on text fields.

So if you *really* need stopwords, add the [StopFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory) to your text field's `analyzer` block. Create a corresponding `stopwords.txt` file in your `solr/conf` directory (the same directory as your `schema.xml`).

(Sunspot configs should actually come with a sample `stopwords.txt` file by default.)